# Copy files from host system to docker image before starting the container

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to build RPMs inside container `first` and then copy these RPMs to the host machine using the `docker cp` command.

Now, I need to install these RPMs in the `second` container. I can simply do `docker cp` to copy the files into the running `second` container.

But, the problem is I'm trying to pull the image, execute a command (not written by me) that ***runs the docker container, runs various commands inside the container and removes the container***. Since this step is automated, I can't run the container and then copy the file. I have to preload the RPMs into the image that I pulled already. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What version of docker can you use for this, can you upgrade to at least 17.05? And can you build your own image and run that?

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Yes, I can

Comment: Wouldn't be useful to mount a volume where the rpm file is generated? so you can preserve that file in the host and avoid to get it deleted when the container does.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways, which involve the creation of a new image.

1. Build another image based on that base image like `FROM image_name:tag`.  Run the commands you want in a `RUN` directive.  Then you can run the container.  This is the cleaner way.
2. Create the container with `docker create`, with the exact parameters you use with `docker run`, and then create a new image with `docker commit` using the `-c` (`--change`) option like this: `docker commit -c 'RUN yum install ... container_name image_name`.

A hackish and ugly way would be to bypass the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` commands with a script that does what you want and then runs the default `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Docker has added multi stage builds in 17.05. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Using this feature, you can have an extra `FROM` line at the top of your second Dockerfile that includes the first image as the first stage. Then you run your copy commands further down to copy the rpm files from your first stage to the second for your tests. If this needs clarification, let me know and I'll post an example when I get to the office tomorrow.

---

Here's an example Dockerfile workflow:

```
FROM first_image:latest as rpmsource

FROM second_base_image:latest
COPY --from=rpmsource /path/in/first_image/*.rpm /path/in/second_image/
CMD ["/script/that/does_stuff_with_rpms.sh"]
```

The two `FROM` lines are a multi-stage build, requiring at least 17.05 to build. The resulting image will only contain the last image unless you build a specific target (see the `docker build --target` option for more details on that). The `COPY` command with the `--from` line can copy files from a later `FROM`.

Comment: yeah! Community and me would be grateful if you can post! Thanks!